# Php and javascript replace regex

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, preg-replace, regression

**PHP regrex**

I want to replace hash+number tag from string with the same hash+number's value and adding link to it as well.

```
$text = The {#0} fox {#1} over the {#2}.
```

I have value against of all hash+number tag and want to replace each hash+number tag with following;

{#0} value is **quick brown** and replace with

```
<span class="get-media-file" name="di-quick-brown">quick brown</span>
```

{#1} value is **jumps** and replace with

```
<span class="get-media-file" name="di-jumps">jumps</span>
```

{#2} value is **lazy dog** and replace with

```
<span class="get-media-file" name="di-lazy dog">lazy dog</span>
```

and final final string will be a html and it will look like .

```
The <span class="get-media-file" name="di-quick-brown">quick brown</span> fox <span class="get-media-file" name="di-jumps">jumps</span> over the <span class="get-media-file" name="di-lazy dog">lazy dog</span>.
```

**Javascript/jquery regrex**

In the admin, the form textarea for the text and inputs for all the hash+numbers and its respective values. I need to count and need to show error message if count mismatch before submitting the form.
*[refer image]* 
[image]

Comment: use str_replace() function

Comment: Please share the code that does not work for you.